# Primes in the open interval

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true that, as n increases through the integers, the number of primes
in the open interval $(n, 2n)$ can stay the same, increase by one, or decrease
by one, but never change by two or more? I don't know how to prove it by induction. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Each time you increase $n$ by one, you lose one number, $n$, and gain $2n+1$ and $2n+2$.

Thus we lose a maximum of $1$ prime, if $n$ was prime.

We gain a maximum of $2$ primes, if $2n+1$ and $2n+2$ are prime, but note that $2n+2$ is even, and thus never prime.